# passing data with async/await in action function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following two functions:

```
async function queryData(){
    const query= await axios.get('...')
    const queryStatus = portNames.map(...);
    const dataStatus= await Promise.all(queryStatus);
    return dataStatus;
}

export function actionData(){
const data = queryData();    
return{
        type:cst.RECEIVE_DATA,
        payload:data 
    }
}
```

queryData() function return after some line code some data in promise...in the second function i put the data in payload for sending my action to reducer.
the problem is that when i'm trying to pass my data from first function in two second, if i output my variable in console.log() inside the second function,it shows:

[image]
  instead if i try to print my variable inside the first function 
  i'm able to access my value from promise...what could be the problem that might create promise pending in actionData()?..therfore how can i pass my data value from promise to action in a way  to dispatch my action with relative data to reducer?

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous functions always return promises. If you want to get access to the value they contain, you either need to call `.then` on the promise, or put your code in an `async` function and `await` the promise.

Since you are using redux, there are some additional considerations. By default, redux does everything synchronously. Dispatching an action should synchronously go through the reducers and update the state. To do async things with redux you'll need to add a middleware. There are a few possible async middlewares, but the one [recommended by the redux team](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-thunks-for-async-logic) is redux-thunk.

With redux-thunk in your project, instead of dispatching an action object, you can dispatch a function. That function is empowered to do async things and dispatch actions when it's done. So a possible implementation for your case would be something like this:

```
function actionData() {
  return async function(dispatch) {
    const data = await queryData();
    dispatch({
      type: cst.RECEIVE_DATA,
      payload: data
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain to you the flow here.

First we come here
`const data = queryData();`

In `queryData` function we have:

```
async function queryData(){
    const query= await axios.get('...')  <------------ first breakpoint ----------------
    // ......
}
```

When this async req is hit, the code doesn't stop it's flow, it continues. Next return statement is hit.

```
return {
  type:cst.RECEIVE_DATA,
  payload:data               // data is undefined at this moment
}
```

In the meantime the async request's response comes back. We sequentially execute the next 3 statements of `queryData()` function

```
    const queryStatus = portNames.map(...);
    const dataStatus= await Promise.all(queryStatus);
    return dataStatus;
```

And now the `data` variable gets updated.

To ensure proper flow, you could write something like this:

```
export async function actionData() {
  const data = await queryData();    
  return {
    type:cst.RECEIVE_DATA,
    payload:data 
  }
}
```

I'd encourage to you read about [async/await on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: hi, if i try to declare async directly on the action...javascript return this " Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions";